# "His mother is both kind and intelligent." - Does it sound natural?

Tags: correlating-conjunctions

This is one of the exercises attached to a textbook:

> His mother is ____ kind ____ intelligent.
>
> A. more, than
>
> B. both, and

The key is **A**, which sounds grammatical (though pretty rude), however is **B** incorrect?

Comment: Option A sounds rude ;)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I agree - that's offensive and embarrassing.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with "His mother's (both) kind and smart"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without worrying whether something is diplomatic, the first is certainly idiomatic and grammatical.

The second is idiomatic and grammatical as well although, as a matter of style, “both” seems slightly odd to me. “Both” seems to imply that the combination of kindness and intelligence is so unusual as to require emphasis. But that is a very subtle issue of style, and other experienced writers might not agree.

Comment: I might say "both" could be about the *unusual*, but more broadly it's about the *unexpected*. If someone were to say or suggest she's only one or the other, you might also respond by saying she's both.

Comment: @NotThatGuy That is a good point.

Answer (score 2):

The second option seems much more likely.  The two adjectives are both positive but one doesn't imply the other, so it is reasonable to want to highlight that a person has both qualities.

The first seems unlikely to me.  It is correct grammar, but you would tend to use the "more X than Y" structure to clarify when quality X could be mistaken for quality Y.  For example a person may appear to do kind things because they are *dutiful*

> Kate can sometimes be cruel
>
> Kate has always been kind to me.
>
> Well, you're her father-in-law.  She is more dutiful than kind.  You should see how she treats her sister.

The combination "more kind than intelligent" could be used if you think someone is going to mistake her kindness for intelligence.  That seems unlikely. It is also a rude thing to say to someone about their mother.  Option A is not a good choice.

I would choose B.